# Why does my film camera not use entire roll of film?

Tags: film, point-and-shoot, olympus

I have a point and shoot olympus mju zoom 105. It had been working perfectly fine with the first few rolls of film but recently whenever I have put a new lot of film in it automatically rewinds the film after taking only 6 photos.
Any ideas as to why this might be happening?
Thanks.

Comment: Did this only happen once? And what did you do next?

Comment: Is it always exactly six?

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem once with 135 film and a Canon EOS 300v.

Turns out, that:

- the battery was quite low (and old)
- it was winter-time outside with -5 °C
- and some idiot (me) had the habit of tightening the film before putting it into the camera.

I did so for years with manually winded cameras. But the electronics measured maybe to much needed force and therefore decided to wind back.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely theories:

- Your batteries are weak.  Replace them.
- There is excessive tension in the winding mechanism that is fooling the camera into thinking that the roll is done.  This would need professional repair, most likely.
- The film is not winding cleanly onto the take-up spool.  Make sure you are loading the film correctly.  If the film engages crookedly, it's possible the camera would experience higher winding tension than it should.
- Overloaded bulk rolls of film can cause similar symptoms.  Make sure you're using commercially-loaded 36-exposure (or fewer) rolls.  (Bulk-loaded film - which is available from a few commercial sources but is usually done at home - should be fine, but is more likely to cause problems.)
- It might just be that the cartridges that manufacturer uses are tighter than other cartridges.  Try another brand of film and see if it's any better.